# animated sprite from multiple sprite sheets

Tags: android, andengine

Im new to android dev and using andengine and ive just come across a problem when dealing with a large animation that covers more then 1 sprite sheet. Basically I have a large sprite whose animation runs across 2 sprite sheets. Im trying to find a way to load them successfully. I will show you what I am trying and hopefully some one can either show me the correct way or help me finish it my way.

i start off by creating the 2 texture packs from the xml files.
these are created fine

```
TexturePackTextureRegionLibrary packer1 = null,packer2 = null;
        TexturePack spritesheetTexturePack1 = null,spritesheetTexturePack2 = null;
        try {
            spritesheetTexturePack1 = new TexturePackLoader(activity.getTextureManager(), "Animation/Jack/")
                    .loadFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "Jack_walk1" + ".xml");
            spritesheetTexturePack1.loadTexture();
            packer1 = spritesheetTexturePack1.getTexturePackTextureRegionLibrary();
        } catch (final TexturePackParseException e) {
            Debug.e(e);
        }

        TexturePackerTextureRegion textureRegion = packer1.get(Jack_walk1.LOOP_JACK_WALK_TO_SAFE_AREA_00000_ID);

        try {
            spritesheetTexturePack2 = new TexturePackLoader(activity.getTextureManager(), "Animation/Jack/")
                    .loadFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "Jack_walk2" + ".xml");
            spritesheetTexturePack2.loadTexture();
            packer2 = spritesheetTexturePack2.getTexturePackTextureRegionLibrary();
        } catch (final TexturePackParseException e) {
            Debug.e(e);
        }

        TexturePackerTextureRegion textureRegion2 = packer2.get(Jack_walk1.LOOP_JACK_WALK_TO_SAFE_AREA_00000_ID);


        ArrayList<SparseArray> animList = new ArrayList<SparseArray>();
        animList.add(packer1.getIDMapping());
        animList.add(packer2.getIDMapping());
        TiledTextureRegion text1 = TiledTextureRegion.create(textureRegion.getTexture(), (int) textureRegion.getTextureX(),  (int) textureRegion.getTextureY(), animList);
```

I then added this function to the tiledtextureregion to take in a list of arrays that hold the frame information and step through adding them to the itexturregion array

```
public static TiledTextureRegion create(final ITexture pTexture, final int pTextureX, final int pTextureY, final ArrayList<SparseArray> animList) {
        ITextureRegion[] textureRegions = null;
        int maxFrame = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < animList.size(); i++){
            maxFrame += animList.get(i).size();
        }
        int currentFrame = 0;
        textureRegions = new ITextureRegion[maxFrame];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < animList.size(); i++){
            SparseArray<? extends ITexturePackTextureRegion> packer = animList.get(i);
            for(int j = 0; j < packer.size(); j++) {
                if (packer.valueAt(j)!= null){

                    final int x = (int) packer.valueAt(j).getTextureX();
                    final int y = (int) packer.valueAt(j).getTextureY();
                    final int width = packer.valueAt(j).getSourceWidth();
                    final int height = packer.valueAt(j).getSourceHeight();
                    final Boolean rotated = packer.valueAt(j).isRotated();


                    textureRegions[currentFrame] = new TextureRegion(pTexture, x, y, width, height, rotated);

                    currentFrame++;
                }
            }
        }


        return new TiledTextureRegion(pTexture, false, textureRegions);
    }
```

but the line return new TiledTextureRegion(pTexture, false, textureRegions); is expecting 1 texture do retrieve the frames from when creating the tiled region. Any ideas where i should go from here or is there a super easy way to handle this that i have over looked. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This class is designed to work with a single texture.

If you cannot merge your textures into one (which I think is the case), then you can try to write a new class implementing ITextureRegion that will contain 2 or more TiledTextureRegion objects, and which will have a method to select one of these at will.
You will just have to delegate the remaining methods of ITextureRegion to the selected object.

```
public class MultipleTextureRegion implements ITextureRegion {
  private List<TiledTextureRegion> internal;
  private int selected=0;

  //...

  public void add(TiledTextureRegion region) {
    internal.add(region);
  }

  public void select(int index) {
    selected=index;
  }

  //...

  // Delegates all ITextureRegion methods ...

  public int getWidth() { return internal.get(selected).getWidth(); }
  // And so on...
  }
```

Comment: would i then need to add a new animate function to animated sprite that handles this? or how would the sprite handle this new textureregion type?

Comment: Hum, yes, you will have to redefine the way you adress the sprites (because you will have to select() the correct page/texture each time you change the sprite). So a rewriting of the animation algorithm will be necessary, I'm afraid.

Comment: im sure you can just picture the colourful language i am using right now! :) thanks for the help